# How would I fix my rotor cipher not properly ciphering?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am currently working on an Enigma project for my Java class (no not that one, the one where you go to learn). However, my Rotor cipher seems to be having a large issue in the fact that it isn't ciphering like it should.

```java
//The rotors i am using are the ones in the first enigma deployed in the german military

    public static String RotorCipher(ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> affine, String input){
        String constructor = "";
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> affine2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>(affine);
        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>(affine.get(0)); //this is a char array with the alphabet in upper case
        affine2.remove(0);
        for(char x : input.toCharArray()){
          int loc = list.indexOf(x);
          if(loc == -1){
            constructor += ""+x; //if it isn't in there, just remove it
          }
          else{
            for(ArrayList<Character> rotor : affine2){
                System.out.println(rotor);
                System.out.println(loc);
                System.out.print(x + " to "); 
                x = AffineCipher(list, rotor, x+"").toCharArray()[0]; //use affine to properly pass rotor
                System.out.println(x);
            }
          }
          constructor += x+"";
        }
        return constructor;
    }
```

I run my code and I pass O through it, which according to a document I have suggests that it should immediately return an S. However, I get this output when passing it through.

```
> >r o
[E, K, M, F, L, G, D, Q, V, Z, N, T, O, W, Y, H, X, U, S, P, A, I, B, R, C, J]
14
O to Y
[A, J, D, K, S, I, R, U, X, B, L, H, W, T, M, C, Q, G, Z, N, P, Y, F, V, O, E]
14
Y to O
[B, D, F, H, J, L, C, P, R, T, X, V, Z, N, Y, E, I, W, G, A, K, M, U, S, Q, O]
14
O to Y
Y
>
```

I have no idea how to fix this and I have wasted hours of my life attempting to solve this but to no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the output that you're not chamging the input and output. In fact it looks like you're outputting the result of the first conversion only.

I would suggest that you break your program into smaller chunks:

1. a function that takes a letter and a rotor and returns the index,
2. a function that takes a letter and a list of rotors that converts the letter through the rotors using function (1).
3. a function that takes a string of letters and a list of rotors and converts the string through the rotors using function (2).

This way you can debug each step in the program and find exactly where a step might go wrong.

Good luck!